# Eval() replacement, but what does it mean? Need explanation

Tags: javascript, eval

I wanted to use eval() function in my code, but found out it can be replaced with `Function('"use strict";return (' + someStringObject + ')')();`.

But... how does it works? What does it mean? Can you explain that to me? It's IIFE function, but what happens inside? How `use strict` converts `someStringObject` to 'normal' object?

Comment: May be this will help [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Comment: It's not `useStrict`, it's a `Function` constructor.

Comment: use strict *doesn't* convert anything. You're building the string e.g. `"\"use strict\";return ({})"`, passing it to Function then calling the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"use strict;"` only prevents the code from creating global variables easily. By using `Function` instead of `eval` the code runs inside of a global function and doesn't have access to the local scope. If we insert a stringified object the code looks like:

```
Function('"use strict";return ({ value: 1 })')();
```

now the function constructor creates a (global) function with the content as it's body:

```
function() {
 "use strict";
 return ({ value: 1 })
 }()
```

That then evaluates to the object as expected. Unlike `JSON.parse`, this also allows functions inside of the string. The usual security considerations apply here - don't trust the client.